# Missing Right Parenthesis in Oracle window function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am getting an error on the following code in Oracle SQL.

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I am trying to count the number of rows within a partition of specific columns and a rolling date window.

```
SELECT Co_ID,
       LOC_ID,
       TYPE_ID,
       SUBTYPE_ID,
       RECORDMONTH,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Co_ID,LOC_ID,TYPE_ID,SUBTYPE_ID 
                        ORDER BY TRUNC(RECORDMONTH)
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '31' DAY PRECEDING
                        AND INTERVAL '31' DAY FOLLOWING) AS "Partner_Count"
```

In a previous CTE I already have RECORDMONTH Converted to date using:

```
to_date(RECORDMONTH,'mm/dd/yyyy') as RECORDMONTH
```

Comment: you need to edit your question and show the COMPLETE SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The `RANK` analytic function does not support the windowing clause.

From the [Analytic Function documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

> In the list of analytic functions that follows, functions followed by an asterisk (*) allow the full syntax, including the `windowing_clause`.
>
> [...]
> RANK

*(Which does not have an asterisk.)*

---

If you do:

```sql
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT 1, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
)
SELECT id,
       value,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY value
         RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
       ) AS rnk
FROM   data;
```

You get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> ```

If you use, for example, `COUNT` then it works:

```sql
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT 1, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
)
SELECT id,
       value,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         ORDER BY value
         RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
       ) AS rnk
FROM   data;
```

| ID | VALUE | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gSttutqN)

Answer (score 1):

Analytic `rank` function you try to use contains *windowing clause*. It is allowed for certain functions, such as `sum`

```
SQL> select sum(sal) over
  2    (partition by deptno, job
  3     order by trunc(hiredate)
  4     range between interval '31' day preceding and interval '31' day following
  5    ) result
  6  from emp
  7  where rownum <= 3;

    RESULT
----------
       860
      3135
      3135
```

or `count`

```
SQL> select count(*) over
  2    (partition by deptno, job
  3     order by trunc(hiredate)
  4     range between interval '31' day preceding and interval '31' day following
  5    ) result
  6  from emp
  7  where rownum <= 3;

    RESULT
----------
         1
         2
         2
```

but not in some other, such as `rank`

```
SQL> select rank(*) over
  2    (partition by deptno, job
  3     order by trunc(hiredate)
  4     range between interval '31' day preceding and interval '31' day following
  5    ) result
  6  from emp
  7  where rownum <= 3;
select rank(*) over
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

or `row_number`:

```
SQL> select row_number(*) over
  2    (partition by deptno, job
  3     order by trunc(hiredate)
  4     range between interval '31' day preceding and interval '31' day following
  5    ) result
  6  from emp
  7  where rownum <= 3;
select row_number(*) over
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

---

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) specifies various options you can use, but it doesn't explain *why* you can't use windowing clause in some functions. All it says (right before listing all functions) is:

> Analytic functions are commonly used in data warehousing environments. In the list of analytic functions that follows, **functions followed by an asterisk (*) allow the full syntax, including the windowing_clause**.

```
AVG *
CLUSTER_DETAILS
CLUSTER_DISTANCE
CLUSTER_ID
CLUSTER_PROBABILITY
CLUSTER_SET
CORR *
COUNT *
<snip>
RANK              --> here's your RANK; no asterisk by its name
<snip>
```

Therefore, all I can say is: you can't use windowing clause in function you chose.